# Python range( ) is not giving me a list

Tags: python, range

Having a beginner issue with Python range.

I am trying to generate a list, but when I enter:

```
def RangeTest(n):

    #

    list = range(n)
    return list

print(RangeTest(4))
```

what is printing is `range(0,4)` rather than `[0,1,2,3]`

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name, not unless you specifically want to mask the built-in type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're using Python 3, where [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range) returns an "immutable sequence type" instead of a list object (Python 2).

You'll want to do:

```
def RangeTest(n):
    return list(range(n))
```

If you're used to Python 2, then `range()` is equivalent to `xrange()` in Python 2.

---

By the way, don't override the `list` built-in type. This will prevent you from even using `list()` as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: Aah, and just realised that list is built-in...

Comment: @Haidro, `This will prevent you from even using list() as I have shown in my answer.` - the `list` type is still available as `__builtins__.list`.

Comment: @kroolik Well yea, :p. or also doing `del list`

Comment: you means for Python >= 3 `range` is `xrange` and original `range` no more exists?

Comment: @Haidro Recently I read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278084/zip-function-giving-incorrect-output-in-python/19278108#19278108) about zip and I notice in new versions of Python all in-build function returns iterator instead of sequences. Is my observation is correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes. `zip()`, `map()` and `filter()` all return iterators in python 3. You can do this in python 2 using the `itertools` module. I'd link you, but I'm on my phone, sorry