# zip function giving incorrect output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some cryptographic algorithm using Python, but I have never worked with Python before.

First of all, look at this code then I'd explain the issue,

```
x = bytearray(salt[16:])
y = bytearray(sha_512[32:48])
c = [  i ^ j for i, j in zip( x, y )  ]
```

The value of x and y are ,

```
bytearray(b'AB\xc8s\x0eYzr2n\xe7\x06\x93\x07\xe2;')
bytearray(b'+q\xd4oR\x94q\xf7\x81vN\xfcz/\xa5\x8b')
```

I couldn't understand the third line of the code. In order to understand the third line, I had to look into the function `zip()`, 
I came across this question,

[zip function help with tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693559/zip-function-help-with-tuples)

According to answer in this question,
the code,

```
zip((1,2,3),(10,20,30),(100,200,300))
```

will output,

```
[(1, 10, 100), (2, 20, 200), (3, 30, 300)]
```

but when I am trying to print it,

```
print(zip((1,2,3),(10,20,30),(100,200,300)))
```

I am getting this output,

```
<zip object at 0x0000000001C86108>
```

Why my output is different from the original output ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python 3 [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#zip) returns an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), use `list` to see its content:

```
>>> list(zip((1,2,3),(10,20,30),(100,200,300)))
[(1, 10, 100), (2, 20, 200), (3, 30, 300)]
```

`c = [  i ^ j for i, j in zip( x, y )  ]` is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), in this you're iterating over the items returned from `zip` and doing some operation on them to create a new list.

Comment: @Xufyan That's a list comprehension.

Comment: @Xufyan Read: [Iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator). `<zip object at 0x0000000001C86108> ` is nothing but a `repr` representation of the zip iterator object.

Comment: I notice in new version of Python most of in-build functions returns iterator instead of sequence. correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, `map` also returns an iterator now and `xrange()` is renamed to `range()`, and the py2.x's `range()` is not available anymore.

Comment: @hcwhsa Thanks! Can you suggest me a source where from I should explore about libraries like iteratools, Collections etc. (or Python docs are best resource).. I saw learn python good book.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Docs are the best resource to learn about libraries, I guess no book covers these libraries properly. BTW to learn some new tricks I'd suggest: [Python Cookbook, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027072.do), a python2 version of this book is also available.