# How to unpack a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, argument-unpacking

This may be a duplicate question, but I want to find out is there a way to unpack a list of lists and make a variable from an unpacked result? I have a data in the file  like:

```
'[416213688, 422393399, 190690902, 81688],| [94925847, 61605626, 346027022],| [1035022, 1036527, 1038016]'
```

So I open a file and make it a list

```
with open ('data.txt', "r") as f:
   a = f.read()
a = a.split("|")
print(*a)
```

Output:

`[416213688, 422393399, 190690902, 81688],  [94925847, 61605626, 346027022],  [1035022, 1036527, 1038016]`

This is the output I need for next step of my program. 
But I can't make this result `a` variable for using it further. It gives me a `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here` if I try:

```
a = (*a)
```

I tried making it by using `zip`, but it gives me incorrect output, similar to what is described in the question [**zip function giving incorrect output**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278084/zip-function-giving-incorrect-output).

```
<zip object at 0x0000000001C86108>
```

So is there any way to unpack a list of list and get an output like:

```
[1st list of variables], [2nd  list of variables], [etc...]
```

if i use  itertools i get:

```
   l = list(chain(*a))
   Out: ['[', '4', '1', '6', '2', '1', '3', '6'...
```

that is not required

So the working option is https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146432/8589220:

```
 row_strings = a.split(",| ")
 grid = [[int(s) for s in row[1:-1].split(", ")] for row in row_strings]
 print(",".join(map(str, grid)))
```

Comment: You can try list comprehensions like [x for l in list for x in l].

Comment: Zip doesn't give 'incorrect output', you might be using it incorrectly. It's also not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish - your data is in a variable and that variable contains a list of lists.

Comment: You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain): `from itertools import chain; l = list(chain(*a))`.

Comment: Are you looking for [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `split()` returns a list. So calling `a = list(a)` is redundant. Does this unpacked variable need to be an iterable or a single line of strings/ints/chars?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect `a = (*a)` to do; and as noted, `a = list(a)` is redundant at that point in the program. It *vaguely looks like* what you're *really trying to do* is take a string like `"[1, 2, 3]"` and convert it into the list `[1, 2, 3]`. Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to parse the string into a two-dimensional grid (i.e.: a list, which itself contains a list of integers):

```
row_strings = a.split(",| ")
grid = [[int(s) for s in row[1:-1].split(", ")] for row in row_strings]
print("\n".join(map(str, grid)))
# Out:
# [416213688, 422393399, 190690902, 81688]
# [94925847, 61605626, 346027022]
# [1035022, 1036527, 1038016]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the raw output (I'm just manually going to make the string, but this is equivalent to your read method)

```
a = '[416213688, 422393399, 190690902, 81688],| [94925847, 61605626, 346027022],| [1035022, 1036527, 1038016]'
```

This is now just one long string. Let's make it a list of strings

```
a = a.split(',|')
```

I did ',|' instead of just '|' because you'll want to get rid of the comma too.

Now a looks like this:

```
>>> ['[416213688, 422393399, 190690902, 81688]', ' [94925847, 61605626, 346027022]', ' [1035022, 1036527, 1038016]']
```

It's a list of strings that look like arrays. Let's turn those strings into arrays of integers. One way we can do that is with [**ast.literal_eval()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). What it does is takes a string as the argument and attempts to interpret whatever is in that string as a Python literal. It doesn't like leading whitespace, so we remove that first with `.strip()`.

```
import ast
a = [ast.literal_eval(arr.strip()) for arr in a]
```

What this does is it takes each string in `a`, `literal_eval`'s it, and puts those into a list.

This should return the code you want.

```
[[416213688, 422393399, 190690902, 81688], [94925847, 61605626, 346027022], [1035022, 1036527, 1038016]]
```